# Grouping subsequent dates into bins

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, group-by, lead

Assuming I have the following table:

```
date         version  
2015-02-01   v1
2015-02-02   v1
2015-02-03   v1
2015-02-04   v1
2015-02-02   v2
2015-02-03   v2
2015-02-08   v1
2015-02-09   v1
```

My query shall group dates in such way I get this result:

```
datefrom      dateto      version
2015-02-01    2015-02-04  v1
2015-02-08    2015-02-09  v1
2015-02-02    2015-02-03  v2
```

I tried something with

```
LEAD(date) OVER(PARTITION BY version ORDER BY date)
```

but it did not really pay off since I cannot group the "bins" of dates.
I want to group each subsequent date into on bin allowing no date gap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with comparing row number with datediff to a fixed date, and if the difference of those changes, then there must be at least a gap of one day. So, something like this:

```
select
  version,
  min (date) as datefrom,
  max (date) as dateto
from
  (
    select
      version,
      date,
      datediff(day, '20100101', date) 
      - row_number() over (partition by version order by date) as bin
    from
      version
  ) T
group by
  version,
  bin
order by
  version,
  datefrom
```

Comment: i do use sql server 2012, can you explain how this query can be simplified with lag/lead?

Comment: Sorry, of course lag / lead are good for finding the gaps, not the islands themselves. I think this is the best way in 2012 too.

Comment: You sir are a genious :) i really tried some time to even get your idea of binning. I got it now and i thought i already saw everything ;). Thank you for that challenging moment.